# How to convert token into a timestamp in SYSTEM$LAST_CHANGE_COMMIT_TIME in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to get the last refresh date of table using a system function SYSTEM$LAST_CHANGE_COMMIT_TIME

select  SYSTEM$LAST_CHANGE_COMMIT_TIME( 'table_name') -- returning a  token

when I try
select  to_timestamp_LTZ( SYSTEM$LAST_CHANGE_COMMIT_TIME( 'table_name')/1000) -- Invalid date

can anyone please help ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You should note that the Snowflake documentation strongly discourages the use of the output of SYSTEM$LAST_CHANGE_COMMIT_TIME as a timestamp. Given that, …

The output of this function is epoch seconds so you just need to convert it to a timestamp e.g.

```
to_timestamp_LTZ( SYSTEM$LAST_CHANGE_COMMIT_TIME( 'table_name'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work
to_timestamp_LTZ(to_varchar( SYSTEM$LAST_CHANGE_COMMIT_TIME( 'table_name')))